# upgrade 1.7 magento conflicts

Tags: magento, upgrade, conflict

My upgrade to Magento 1.7 via ssh is failing. 
Does anyone know a solution?

This is the output:

thnx!

```
root@****:/var/www/vhosts/****.nl/httpdocs# ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17158657 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/****.nl/httpdocs/downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Abstract.php on line 45
Checking dependencies of packages
Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml failed: Detected Mage_Core_Adminhtml conflict of versions: 1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0 and 1.6.1.0-1.7.0.0
Package community/Mage_Core_Modules failed: Detected Mage_Core_Modules conflict of versions: 1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0 and 1.5.0.1-1.6.0.0
Installing package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.0.0
Package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.5.0.0
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.5.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.7.0.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.0
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.0
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
```

//////// UPDATE /////////

I increased the memory_limit in php.ini and tried again.
The results are better now, only one conflict in the top.

The website is still not working. It's showing me the installation wizard. 
I tried to download it on that way. But, when i continue, it's redirecting me to the same download page..

I've got a backup. ;)

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
Checking dependencies of packages
Package community/Lib_ZF failed: couldn't connect to host
Package community/Mage_Core_Modules failed: Detected Mage_Core_Modules conflict of versions: 1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0 and 1.5.0.1-1.6.0.0
Installing package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.0.0
Package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.5.0.0
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.5.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.7.0.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.0
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.0
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.3
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.3 installed successfully
Installing package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.6.0.0
Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.6.0.0
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.6.0.0
Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Mage_Downloader 1.6.0.0
Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Mage_Centinel 1.6.0.0
Package community/Mage_Centinel 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.6.0.0
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.0
Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Find_Feed 1.1.0
Package community/Find_Feed 1.1.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Mage_Compiler 1.6.0.0
Package community/Mage_Compiler 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Magento_Mobile 1.5.0.0.21.0
Package community/Magento_Mobile 1.5.0.0.21.0 installed successfully
Installing package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.6.0.0
Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Starting to download Lib_Js_Calendar-1.51.1.tgz ...
...done: 24,627 bytes
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1
Package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1 installed successfully
Starting to download Lib_Js_Ext-1.6.0.0.tgz ...
...done: 267,847 bytes
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.6.0.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.6.0.0 installed successfully
Starting to download Lib_LinLibertineFont-2.8.14.0.tgz ...
...done: 1,430,498 bytes
Installing package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.0
Package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.0 installed successfully
Starting to download Lib_Js_TinyMCE-3.3.7.0.tgz ...
...done: 909,906 bytes
Installing package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.3.7.0
Package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.3.7.0 installed successfully
Package installed: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.5.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.7.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.3
Package installed: community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Install_Default 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Downloader 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Centinel 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.0
Package installed: community/Find_Feed 1.1.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Compiler 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Magento_Mobile 1.5.0.0.21.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.6.0.0
Package installed: community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.3.7.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
Mage is a PHP script that runs by phpcli instead of the normal php.
The memory_limit for phpcli was by default 32MB. So phpcli handles an other php configuration. (didn't know that, i'm not very similar with servers)

The upgrade worked after increasing the memory_limit in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Your php cli php.ini file could do with some attention to get rid of those warnings and have more than 32MB? of memory.

As for the problem in hand, why don't you just install with the gui a new Magento build over the 1.6 db? It will update itself, add columns to tables and so forth.

Then you can run the database check against a vanilla 1.7 install and patch any problems with the db that have collected over the years.

Finally, you can then put your modules and theme back in.

That is an upgrade path, not the simple couple of clicks you were hoping for! Just make sure you have everything backed up.

Comment: I have updated the memory_limit to 512M in php.ini and my htaccess.
Phpinfo, confirms this change. Even than, i've got the same error.
So, on someway the script is taking another memory_limit. But i don't know where. When i put a phpinfo in the same dir as the error belongs to, the memory_limit is stil 512M.